# Issue with JSON String in php

Tags: php, json

I have an issue with a json string.

I send this json string in Postman,

```
{
 "places": [
       {
         "longitude": "79.9304633",
         "latitude": "6.720229199999999",
         "city": "Panadura"
       },
       {
         "longitude": "79.86296829999999",
         "latitude": "6.855948499999999",
         "city": "Dehiwala"
       }
  ]
}
```

But in the server side, when I get this value using this,

```
$jsonPlaces = $_POST['jsonplaces'];
```

and the value of $jsonPlaces looks like this,

```
{\\\"places\\\":[{\\\"longitude\\\":\\\"79.9304633\\\",\\\"latitude\\\":\\\"6.720229199999999\\\",\\\"city\\\":\\\"Panadura\\\"},{\\\"longitude\\\":\\\"79.86296829999999\\\",\\\"latitude\\\":\\\"6.855948499999999\\\",\\\"city\\\":\\\"Dehiwala\\\"}]}
```

therefore json_encode() function doesn't work for the above string since json syntax is changed.
How to fix this issue?

Thanks

Comment: try using `stripslashes($_POST['jsonplaces'])`

Comment: yeah it worked, thanks, post this as a answer plz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `stripslashes($_POST['jsonplaces'])` to remove additional slashes.

Answer (score 0):

Probably Postman uses the [`addslashes`](http://php.net/addslashes) method to escape the (JSON) string before inputing it in the DB, as mentioned in comment, you should use the inverse function [`stripslashes`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php) to un-escape the string before doing  the [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) function